# Do I need 50 URL Variations for a single URL for hreflang?

Tags: seo, google-search, hreflang

I have a website which is listing merchants and their offers. Every merchant is selling to one or more countries. Let's make it about televisions.

```
Merchant A ships to US, CA
Merchant B ships to US, DE, NL 
Merchant C ships to DE, CA, FR, ES, PT
Merchant D ships to ES, PT
etc. (30+ merchants)
```

Based on the visitors region, I want to show only the merchants which are selling to that visitors country. Now everything on the page will be the same, a description about the television. The only thing that is different, is the list of merchants, and the schema.org offers data.

I assume I have to create the following pages and their hreflang tags in order to have the proper url listed in the search results, but to what extend?

Lets say I am targeting 50 countries. Do I need to have 50 versions of every single page on my website?

```
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com" hreflang="en-us" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/ca" hreflang="en-ca" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/fr" hreflang="en-fr" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/de" hreflang="en-de" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/pt" hreflang="en-pt" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/nl" hreflang="en-nl" />
<link rel="alternate" href="http://example.com/es" hreflang="en-es" />
```

Comment: You wouldn't normally make language country combinations we're very few people speak that language in the country. Why wouldn't you translate your site into French so that you can use fr-fr rather than en-fr?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Thanks for your response. 50 languages would require high maintenance, I don't have such resources. The question is, would adding the suggested urls/href alternatives make Google properly serve the correct page with the specific offers for that country. Or Should I just have one page and display the offers based on users IP.